# Subsampling a dataframe based on mininum and maximum non-zero elements in rows

Tags: r

I have a count matrix with many zero elements:

```
my.matrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(100 * 1000, 1, 0.5), ncol = 100, nrow = 1000))
```

(in reality, the range of the non-zero integers are between 1 and 12,000, but i couldnt find a better example. My dataset does not contain only 0 and 1).

I would like to randomly select n rows (n=100, e.g.) with at least x n but no more than y non-zero elements:

```
n = number of randomly selected rows 
x = minimum amount of non-zero elements in a row
y = maximum amount of non-zero elements in a row
```

How to do that? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If all columns are numeric, is there a particular reason to use frames? A `matrix` would be significantly faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is numeric then stick with a matrix and don't coerce it into a dataframe. There's a computational cost to converting types, and in this case the dataframe doesn't offer any obvious advantage. Using some slightly different data:

```r
set.seed(12345)
my.matrix <- matrix(sample(c(sample.int(12000, 90000, T), rep(0, 10000))),
                    ncol = 100,
                    nrow = 1000
                    )
```

Get the row sums of the logical matrix created by `my.matrix != 0`, which is TRUE for non-zero values. Then set your upper and lower thresholds, do your comparison in `which` to get the indices for all rows that contain at least `x` and at most `y` non-zero values, draw a sample of n = 100 from that, and use the resulting indices to subset your dataframe:

```r
rs <- rowSums(my.matrix != 0)

x <- 85 # lower threshold
y <- 90 # upper threshold

my.matrix[sample(which(rs >= x & rs <= y), 100),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting a seed for reproducible random data:

```r
set.seed(2)
my.matrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(100 * 1000, 1, 0.5), ncol = 100, nrow = 1000))
```

Functions like `apply` and `rowSums` will convert the data into a `matrix`. If any if your included columns are `character`, then everything will be converted and things might not behave as you'd like. The use of `isnum` is merely to make sure you do not inadvertently include it (even though this actual sample data has nothing wrong):

```r
isnum <- sapply(my.matrix, is.numeric)
sums <- rowSums(my.matrix[,isnum] != 0)
head(sums)
# [1] 51 60 53 45 42 56
table(sums)
# sums
# 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 
#  2  2  1  7 11 20 21 37 36 49 46 64 72 71 59 79 72 77 76 52 48 33 21 14 11 10 
# 62 63 64 70 
#  1  5  2  1
```

From here, just subset the range manually.

```r
my.matrix[ 37 < sums & sums < 40, 1:4 ]
#     V1 V2 V3 V4
# 69   0  0  1  1
# 202  1  0  0  1
# 228  0  1  0  0
# 293  1  0  1  0
# 306  0  1  0  0
# 363  0  1  1  0
# 810  0  0  1  1
# 890  1  0  1  1
```

You can also use `dplyr::between` or `data.table::between` for more-succinct code, though it does not add any capability over this.

As for sampling, it is straight-forward sampling once you have this info:

```r
ind <- which(37 < sums & sums < 40)
ind <- sample(ind, min(length(ind), 100))
my.matrix[ ind, 1:4 ]
#     V1 V2 V3 V4
# 363  0  1  1  0
# 202  1  0  0  1
# 228  0  1  0  0
# 890  1  0  1  1
# 306  0  1  0  0
# 69   0  0  1  1
# 810  0  0  1  1
# 293  1  0  1  0
```

I did the `max(...)` in case you have *fewer* than 100 in your resulting vector. Without `max`, you might see `cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'`.

Comment: I think you need non-zero rowSums (```!=0```) and the number of randomly selected rows. +1 on thorough answer.

Comment: "equal", "not-equal", it's all the same ... err, right. Good catch.